# Ajax content-disposition returns null, while network show correct information

Tags: jquery, ajax, download, content-disposition

I got a download working, but I am unable to get the content disposition. It keeps returning null, but in the network I can see it is available:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9A1W.png)

Then I have the code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7KnH.png)

And the download goes correct, but when I look at the console, i see no content-disposition and therefor I cannot determine the original filename:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QJeD.png)

I have tried multiple things, case sensitive, different browsers etc, but I am unable to get the content-disposition. I remains returning null. Any idea if I am missing something?

Also I checked multiple sites and solution through search, but unable to get it working!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try with `content-disposition` instead of `Content-Disposition` in your code (2nd screen)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but tried multiple case sensitive items, but all gave null as result.